# Translate GUI from another language?

Tags: windows, gui, translation

translate.google.com can translate texts and sites from language to language.

What about translating GUI, i.e. window titles, button captions and etc?

Are there some software acting like this?

Need this for Windows.

Comment: The problem is that these texts are not stored in a standardized format. It turns out that this is heavily dependent on the programming language. If you're aware of the programming language, please add it to the question. I was working for 2 companies now, and each company finally implemented their own translation tool :-(

Comment: Paid or gratis?

Comment: Maybe you can convert to text using [FineReader](https://pdf.abbyy.com/) and translate with any translation program.

Comment: [Google Lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Lens) is a smartphone app theat tries to detect foreign texts in your smartphone-camera viewfinder picture and translates them in near-realtime to your preferred language.

Answer (score 2):

Gratis solution: You can take a screenshot of the GUI and upload the image to https://translate.google.com/ or some other image translation service.

Not efficient if the text in the GUI often changes, but that could be automated to some extent with an image translation service API.